# Filtering requests in NGINX using Shibboleth headers

Tags: authentication, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

My organization uses Shibboleth SAML authentication. Currently it works well but I would like some of our servers paths to only be accessible by a handful of people. The main way I have identified to accomplish this is using a map in NGINX but I think because Shibboleth injects headers at some point it is not working for me. Does anyone know how I can accomplish my goal here in a nginx-shibboleth compliant way? I have tried many variations of the `$http_eppn` `$http_upstream_eppn`, etc... My end goal is to replace the return statement with a `proxy pass` to a application.

in http block:

```
map $http_eppn $allowed_eppn {
     "eppn1" 1;
     "eppn2" 1;
     "eppn3" 1;
     default 0;
}
```

Used later on:

```
location /test {
   shib_request_use_headers on;
   include shib_clear_headers;
   more_clear_input_headers 'Remote-User' 'Shib-Identity-Provider' 'Uid' 'Eppn' 'Affiliation';
   shib_request /shibauthorizer;

   if ($is_ok) {
      return 405; 
   }
   add_header Content-Type text/plain;
   return 200 '$http_eppn';
}
```